# What's the meaning of »Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst«?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What does »Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst« mean?

Comment: Please use a search engine for simple translations. E.g. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst (which links to the English WP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomb_disposal)

Comment: @feeela: For your information, that's what I do always before asking any question here. The page you've pasted and other Google results are about its usage, not the definition and its structure like Splattne explained.  Plus, If I could understand the German version of Wikipedia, why in the world would I register here to learn German? Please think more before pinging me for whatever came to your mind, thanks.

Comment: 1. You've asked "what does it mean?" which is the question about the definition not about the word-structure; 2. Wikipedia, for example, is multilingual–once you've found the German entry, you'll mostly have the English one too (as the en:WP is more complete than the de:WP); they are linked vice-versa on the left (under "Languages"); I never told you, to read the German WP-article–it was just one of the first entries, using the English version of Google…

Comment: +close, as too localized. Like feela suggessted: Use different tools for simple translation acts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the word is a noun, it's spelled

> Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst

It's a group of specialists who are in charge of disposing explosive material. In English:

- bomb disposal team
- explosive ordnance disposal

The word is a combination of three nouns:

- Kampfmittel: weapons (Kampf = fight, Mittel = resource)
- Beseitigung: disposal
- Dienst: service

*Kampfmittelräumdienst* is a German synonym for the word.

Comment: IMHO *Kampfmittelräumdienst* is the standard word that is used most of the time, except for specific units in some federal states that are named *Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst*.

Comment: I agree with @starblue. See also [Google Trends – Kampfmittelräumdienst vs. Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst](http://www.google.com/trends?q=Kampfmittelr%C3%A4umdienst,Kampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst&geo=deu).

Comment: Nice Google feature, except for the missing umlauts for cities. :-(

Comment: @starblue see also: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Kampfmittelr%C3%A4umdienst%2CKampfmittelbeseitigungsdienst&year_start=1965&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3